# Check if its home page or not

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get if its home page or not. (I mean all kind of home page in wordpress: Default, static, blog). I wrote this code in `function.php` file but in all pages I get "not home"!!

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {

    die("home");
} elseif ( is_front_page() ) {

    die("home");

} elseif ( is_home() ) {

    die("home");

} else {

    die("not home");

}
```

Comment: and my theme is default `twentytwenty` wordpress theme

Comment: Please check here select homepage or not http://prntscr.com/rbfckh

Comment: @DipakDholakiya I'm trying to develop plugin. and i want this code to work in all kind of home pages. I tried this in function.php first but it didn't work

Comment: But this is required to select homepage other wise this condition does't work

Comment: @DipakDholakiya what about if "Your latest posts" is checked?

Comment: It's consider blog page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set home page screenshot https://prnt.sc/rbfgy8

Add this code in theme functions.php

```
//Put the condition in wp_footer hook to see the result
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_wp_footer_fun');
function custom_wp_footer_fun(){

    if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {

        echo 'home'; 
    } elseif ( is_front_page() ) {

        echo 'home'; 

    } elseif ( is_home() ) {

        echo 'home'; 

    } else {

        echo 'not home'; 

    }

}
```